Worker failed to index functions with Azure Functions & FastAPI local using AsgiMiddleware
Running into an error that has started after a reboot.  I am testing using Azure Functions in conjunction with FastAPI based on: https://dev.to/manukanne/azure-functions-and-fastapi-14b6
Code was operating and test API call worked as expected.  After a reboot of the machine and restarting VSCode I am now running into an issue when attempting to run locally.
I worked through SO: 76842742 which is slightly different setup but similar type of error being seen.
Virtual environment is running as expected and requirements.txt showing installed.  Have run with verbose flag as well but no additional error messages were provided.
Current error:
Worker failed to index functions
Result: Failure Exception: ValueError: Could not find top level function app instances in function_app.py.
My function.json has the scriptFile: init.py which I thought would need to be function_app.py but the error indicates it is looking for the function_app.py regardless.  I created a copy of my function_app.py and named it "__init __.py" as a potential fix but that produced the same error code.
At this point I am at a loss as to why the index function is not being found.  Any thoughts around a potential solution?
Found Python version 3.11.0 (py)
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5611
VS Code: 1.88.1
function_app.py
import azure.functions as func
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import logging

app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def handle_exception(request: Request, exc: Exception):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=400,
        content={"message": str(exc)},
    )

@app.get("/")
async def home():
    return {
        "info": "Try the API path for success"
    }

@app.get("/v1/test/{test}")
async def get_test(
    test: str,):
    return {
        "test": test,
    }

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle_async(req, context)

function.json
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
      {
        "authLevel": "function",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
          "get",
          "post"
        ],
        "route": "/{*route}"
      },
      {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "$return"
      }
    ]
  }

ADDITIONAL ADD
host.json
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/dev/schemas/json/host.json",
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}


Based on a co-pilot suggestion I added an entryPoint reference in the function.json file to point to main.  This did no alter the output of the error.

You are using V1 of the Python runtime, is it possible to switch to V2? Then you can just use this as an example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/

@JarroVGIT I think I am using V2.  I've added my host.json to the overall question/description.  What led you to the idea that this was operating via version 1?

The Python v1 model uses a functions.json file to define functions, and the new v2 model lets you instead use a decorator-based approach. You also have a main function rather than an app object. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators

Here is what I am seeing in the link provided:
@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="req")
def main(req):
user = req.params.get("user")
return f"Hello, {user}!"
Both the code I have above and the example have defined main functions and I have the app function above for FASTAPI which is being passed into the main azzure function via the AsgiMiddleWare.  I'll dig in a bit more but I think the structure is sound.

@JarroVGIT Dug in a little, I think I am seeing the issue you've identified.

Yes on the top of the page, you need to select V2 as programming model, otherwise you will see V1 examples.

Based on comments by JarroVGIT, I refactored the function_app.py code to:
import azure.functions as func
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
import logging

fast_app = FastAPI()

@fast_app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def handle_exception(request: Request, exc: Exception):
    return Response(
        status_code=400,
        content={"message": str(exc)},
    )

@fast_app.get("/")
async def home():
    return {
        "info": "Try the API path for success" 
    }

@fast_app.get("/v1/test/{test}")
async def get_test(
    test: str,):
    return {
        "test": test,
    }

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fast_app,
                           http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS,)

Removing the def main and adding the app call.  This has resolved the issue and allows the azure function to start normally.
